# How to check tree is a full binary tree

Tags: haskell

such that fullA atr determines whether fullA atr is a full binary tree.

```
fullA :: AltTree a -> Bool
fullA (Leaf a) = True
fullA (One a b) = not (fullA b)
fullA (Two a b c) = fullA b && fullA c
```

It work for most of the example, But when I use example: fullA(One 0(One 1(Leaf 2)))
It return True, but it should be return False.
Can someone explain to me?

Answer (score 4):

The line with `(One a b)` does not make much sense, since a [*full tree* is defined as [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees):

> A full binary tree (sometimes referred to as a proper or plane binary tree) is a tree in which **every node has either 0 or 2 children**.

This thus means that if your `AltTree` contains a `One` node, it is not a full binary tree. We thus can implement this as:

```
fullA :: AltTree a -> Bool
fullA (Leaf _) = True
fullA (One _ _) = False  -- we found a node with one one child
fullA (Two _ b c) = fullA b && fullA c
```

---

> **Note**: In Haskell, it is common to use an underscore (`_`) for variables we do not care about. If we turn on the
> [**`-Wunused-matches`**](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-warnings.html#ghc-flag--Wunused-binds) compiler flag,
> it will warn about patterns where the variables are *not* used at the right side of the equation.

Comment: This question reminds me of Alexis King's blog post, "Parse, Don't Validate". The result should *probably* be `Maybe (FullTree a)`, not `Bool`, for any real application.